# How to convert MM/YY to YYYY-MM-DD in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got sample data in below format  (MM/YY).

```
Dt
11/13
4/85
4/84
5/14
09/06
```

I need to convert that data ito YYYY-MM-DD

```
       Dt
    2013-11-01
    1985-04-01
    1984-04-01
    2014-05-01
    2006-09-01
```

I have tried using Date_Format(Dt,%y%m%d) but still it is giving error .

I know this format in the file is not correct but I have got the Data like I need to do a turn around using MYSQL . Any suggestions on this

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` converts a date to a string. But you have a string already. You can convert the string to a date with `STR_TO_DATE`. And then you *can* convert this date to a string, if you want to. Usually we just let dates be dates without converting them to strings in the database (i.e. with SQL). The tool that displays the dates should take care of this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the text into a date:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', Dt), '%d/%m/%y') AS Dt
FROM data
```

Note that it's necessary to add a day to the string to avoid issues if `NO_ZERO_DATE` or `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` SQL modes are enabled.

Output:

```
Dt
2013-11-01
1985-04-01
1984-04-01
2014-05-01
2006-09-01
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a05d61/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('12/12', "%m/%y"), '%Y-%m-01');
```

`STR_TO_DATE("12/12", "%m/%y")` will convert the string to a date format. `DATE_FORMAT` functino will convert the date to str making the day `01`.
You can convert it back to DATE if needed.